# numpy shape: rearranging axes to get desired format

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, shapes

I have a numpy array, 'a', of shape (52,). When I do a[0].shape, I get (8,8,6). How do I modify 'a' to get a.shape to be equal to (52,8,8,6)?

I have tried reshaping the array, but have failed to obtain the desired shape.

Comment: I don't think you can. `reshape` requires that the total size of your array remains the same, resizing a `(52,)` to `(52, 8, 8, 6)` effectively extends your array for `8*8*6` dimensions. And what would be the point? `reshape` is there to i.e. convert a 9 element ndarray to a 3x3 2D ndarray. What you're talking about sounds like you want to make copies of your array[0] into an extended version of your array.

Comment: Please show a minimal code example that results in the construction of that numpy array a with singular shape.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a NumPy array of dtype `object`, which contains 52 arrays of shape (8,8,6):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty(52, dtype='O')
a[:] = [np.random.random((8,8,6)) for i in range(52)]
```

so that

```
In [38]: a.shape
Out[38]: (52,)

In [39]: a[0].shape
Out[39]: (8, 8, 6)
```

Assuming all 52 arrays have the same shape and dtype, you could convert it to an array of shape (52,8,8,6) by using `np.fromiter` and a generator expression to flatten the values:

```
b = (np.fromiter(
    (val for arr in a for val in arr.ravel()), 
    count=(a.size)*(a[0].size), dtype=a[0].dtype)
     .reshape(a.shape+a[0].shape))
```

---

```
In [40]: b.shape
Out[40]: (52, 8, 8, 6)
```

---

Note that NumPy numerical operations are much much quicker when performed on arrays of numerical dtype -- **not** `object` dtype. So ideally, you want to avoid creating the array `a` in the first place. Instead of using `np.fromiter`, you might be best off reworking the code which defines `a` so the desired array of shape (52, 8, 8, 6) is built from the start.